# If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are primes, prove that there exists an integer such that $p_1+k$ is a prime but $p_2+k$ is not.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ be primes. Prove that there exists a $k\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $P_{1} + k$ is a prime but $P_{2} + k$ is not.

It seems like the proof should be trivial, but for some reason, I am not able to construct it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are different primes, can you not just choose $k = p_2$? Then $p_2 + p_2 = 2p_2$ is certainly not prime, but $p_1 + p_2$ has *no* prime factors, therefore prime?

I may be missing something though! (Turns out I'm missing most of my brain cells today! This is obviously wrong)

Comment: @TheMathsGeek $p_1 + p_2$ is probably even, so not a prime.

Comment: Hmm, this certainly follows from Direchlet (which gives infinitely many such $k$). But I am missing an elementary argument.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft Ha, of course it's likely even - it's been a long day already, maybe I'll wait to answer after I've had a coffee next time!

Comment: @TheMathsGeek I was typing the same idea when I saw your comment. Only then did I realize it was not correct.

Comment: Sorry i deleted the comment that Tobias is replying to above. Yeah, it seems like p1+p2 might not be a prime.

Comment: Silly question: Am I missing something, or would it suffice to find one triplet $(P_1,P_2,k)$ that satisfies the conditions to prove that "there exists a $k$..."? (In which case one could pick $P_1=5$, $P_2=7$, and $k=2$.)

Comment: Not to be a stick in the mud, but the inconsistency of notation between the question title and the question body is bothering me. I'm not sure it rises to the level that makes it worth editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a more elementary approach than just quoting Dirichlet.

Suppose $P_2\gt P_1$ and $P_2-P_1=d$. If $P_3=P_1+k$ we want $P_3+d=P_2+k$ not to be a prime.

So given $d$ we need to find a prime $P_3$ with $P_3+d$ not a prime.

Now we know that there are arbitrarily large gaps between primes e.g. $n!+2, \dots n!+n$ gives a gap of size at least $n-1$. (all these are composite by construction, so the prime before and the prime after will have a big gap)

We can choose $n\gt d+1$ here, so there will be a $P_3$ distance greater than $d$ from the next prime, and we can choose $k$ to pick this out.

Comment: NIce!  I knew there had to be a more elementary proof: thank you!

Comment: Don't you lose some generality by assuming P2 > P1? You can't just switch them, because the problem statement asks specifically for P1+k to be prime and P2+k not to be, rather than asking for one of them to be prime and the other not.

Comment: @amalloy Not really, I just want $d$ to be positive. If they are the other way around I can define $d$ equivalently.

Answer (score 13):

Note that the numbers $P_1+nP_2, n\in \mathbb N$ are in arithmetic progression and this contains (by Dirichlet) infinitely many primes. So choose $n\ge 1$ which makes this a prime. $P_2+nP_2$ is clearly not prime.

Comment: This does use a fact about primes which is not so easy to prove. Maybe there is an easier way, but it is not obvious apart from the case $P_1=2$ when $k$ has to be odd and $P_2+k$ is even - this could be seen as using the odd numbers as the arithmetic progression, and there is a relatively easy proof that there are infinitely many odd primes.

Comment: yeah, I had never heard of Dirichlet progression. This came up in a proof regarding formal languages, so am assuming the author of the textbook expected me to prove the claim some other way. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assume wlog $p_1 < p_2$ and $p_1+k$ is prime iff $p_2+k$ is prime. Set $z:=p_2-p_1$. By induction, $p_1+nz$ is prime for all $n$. This is impossible since the primes have density zero.

Comment: As noted in a comment to my answer, it's enough to see it's not prime for $n=p_1$.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Same proof but significantly cleaned up.

Suppose this is not true, and let $p_2 > p_1$.  Then for $k=p_2-p_1$, we have $p_1 + k$ is prime, so $p_2 + k$ is prime.  We also have $p_1 + (k+p_2-p_1)$ is prime then, so $p_1 + 2\cdot(p_2-p_1)$ is prime.  Continuing in this way we get that $p_1 + n\cdot(p_2-p_1)$ is prime for all $n$, which is not possible.

Comment: To make the last point clearer, plug in $n=p_1$.

Comment: I don't get it ... say $p_1=7$ and $p_2=13$. Then $k=p_2+p_1=20$, so $p_1+k=27$ .. is not prime ...

Comment: I don't follow. Showing that this works for some $k$ doesn't seem to imply that there's **no** $k$ for which this works.

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks, I typoed.  Should have been $p_2 - p_1$.

Comment: @LivingRobot Working by contradiction.  If there is no $k$ such that $p_1 + k$ is prime but $p_2 + k$ is not, then $p_1 + k$ prime implies $p_2 + k$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We must assume $P_1 \ne P_2$ for this to be true. Now, what would the world look like if this were false?
Well, take $d = |P_1 - P_2|$. If this were false, then either for all $x$ $x \ge P_1$ being prime implies $x + d$ is also prime, or for all $x$ $x \ge P_2$ being NOT prime implies $x + d$ is also NOT prime. In either case, deduce the following absurd fact:

- The function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, defined by $f(n) = 1$ if $n$ is prime and $f(n) = 0$ otherwise, is **eventually periodic with period $d$.**

From here there are probably multiple ways to derive a contradiction. One idea: there are infinitely many primes, so there must be some $N$ such that $N, N + d$, $N + 2d$, $N + 3d$, etc. are all prime. Now pick $k$ so that $N + kd$ just certainly cannot be prime.

Comment: Yeah, I was following this same train of thought myself, but didn't quite know how to get that contradiction in the first case ... could you please elaborate on that, please?

Comment: @Bram28 I edited to clarify the main point of the argument. The last sentence of the new version of my answer may answer your question. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, still struggling to see it ... I *feel* it has to be true, but maybe this proof does require a big gun after all ...

Comment: @Bram28 No big gun! Just take $k = N$. Or are you asking about he earlier part of the proof?